# Use of next in passport.js and express router

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

We have such express.js route with passport. I have noticed the use of the next promise, however if I delete it, my tests work fine anyway, for 409 and 201 responses. Any idea if it is really needed in such context:

```
exports.signUp = (req, res, next) ->
  passport.authenticate('local-signup', (err, user, next) ->
    if err
      res.status(409).send
        status: 'Conflict'
        error: 'Benutzername bereits vergeben'
        type: 'warning'
      return
    else if user != false and user != ''
      token = jwt.sign({ user: user }, secret.secretToken, expiresInMinutes: 60 * 60)
      res.status(201).send
        status: 'Created'
        error: 'Benutzer erstellt'
        type: 'success'
        token: token
        user: user
    return
  ) req, res, next
  return
```

*note: it's coffeescript*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use it in the callback passed to `passport.authenticate`, you can leave it out. However, `passport.authenticate` itself will probably need it to handle certain situations (this is a guess, I haven't dug into the Passport code to make sure).

So your could rewrite your code to this:

```
exports.signUp = (req, res, next) ->
  passport.authenticate('local-signup', (err, user) ->
    ...
  ) req, res, next
  return
```

Which isn't much of an improvement.

As a warning: your code leaves some situations where a response isn't sent, namely if `user` is false or an empty string (in that situation you just `return` instead of sending a response).

Comment: Ok I see, I will have to dig more into passport.js then. As for the guard analysis - many thanks!

Comment: Could you add a bit of light to the use of req res next triple in the last lines?

Comment: @SirBenBenji `passport.authenticate()` returns a function (a middleware function, to be exact), and that function is subsequently called with `req, res, next` as arguments.